# Ruby - Hash to Array - Accessing Keys

Tags: ruby

I'm a little uncomfortable using chain of methods in Ruby. Here, I'm using such a chain.

So the question is, Tell me a better way to do the same.

I have this line run,

```
p["All_Products"]["Product"].map{|h| h["Categories"]["Category"] rescue nil }.compact.flatten.uniq
```

`p` equals this,

```
{"All_Products"=>
  {"Product"=>
    [{"ProductCode"=>"GFT",
      "Categories"=>
       {"Category"=>
         [{"CategoryID"=>"1513", "CategoryName"=>"Beauty"},
          {"CategoryID"=>"1515", "CategoryName"=>"Specials"},
          {"CategoryID"=>"1553", "CategoryName"=>"Bath and Body"}]}},
     {"ProductCode"=>"GF-honey",
      "Categories"=>
       {"Category"=>
         [{"CategoryID"=>"1514", "CategoryName"=>"Gourmet Food"},
          {"CategoryID"=>"1515", "CategoryName"=>"Specials"},
          {"CategoryID"=>"1632", "CategoryName"=>"Specialty Items"}]}},
     {"ProductCode"=>"GF-malbec",
      "Categories"=>
       {"Category"=>
         [{"CategoryID"=>"1514", "CategoryName"=>"Gourmet Food"},
          {"CategoryID"=>"1632", "CategoryName"=>"Specialty Items"}]}},
     {"ProductCode"=>"GF-olives",
      "Categories"=>
       {"Category"=>
         [{"CategoryID"=>"1514", "CategoryName"=>"Gourmet Food"},
          {"CategoryID"=>"1632", "CategoryName"=>"Specialty Items"}]}},
     {"ProductCode"=>"HC-flatiron",
      "Categories"=>
       {"Category"=>
         [{"CategoryID"=>"1513", "CategoryName"=>"Beauty"},
          {"CategoryID"=>"1515", "CategoryName"=>"Specials"},
          {"CategoryID"=>"1554", "CategoryName"=>"Hair Care"}]}}
    ]
  } 
}
```

Finally I'm getting this,

```
[{"CategoryID"=>"1513", "CategoryName"=>"Beauty"},
 {"CategoryID"=>"1515", "CategoryName"=>"Specials"},
 {"CategoryID"=>"1553", "CategoryName"=>"Bath and Body"},
 {"CategoryID"=>"1514", "CategoryName"=>"Gourmet Food"},
 {"CategoryID"=>"1632", "CategoryName"=>"Specialty Items"},
 {"CategoryID"=>"1554", "CategoryName"=>"Hair Care"},
 {"CategoryID"=>"1673", "CategoryName"=>"Sweets"},
 {"CategoryID"=>"1477", "CategoryName"=>"Home Decor"},
 {"CategoryID"=>"1516", "CategoryName"=>"Furniture"},
 {"CategoryID"=>"1517", "CategoryName"=>"Home Accessories"},
 {"CategoryID"=>"1814", "CategoryName"=>"Apparel"},
 {"CategoryID"=>"1815", "CategoryName"=>"Women"},
 {"CategoryID"=>"1816", "CategoryName"=>"Men"}]
```

Comment: What's the question exactly? A better way to do the same?

Comment: Yes a better way to do the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will this help?:

```
products = {"All_Products"=>
  {"Product"=>
    [{"ProductCode"=>"GFT",
      "Categories"=>
       {"Category"=>
         [{"CategoryID"=>"1513", "CategoryName"=>"Beauty"},
          {"CategoryID"=>"1515", "CategoryName"=>"Specials"},
          {"CategoryID"=>"1553", "CategoryName"=>"Bath and Body"}]}},
     {"ProductCode"=>"GF-honey",
      "Categories"=>
       {"Category"=>
         [{"CategoryID"=>"1514", "CategoryName"=>"Gourmet Food"},
          {"CategoryID"=>"1515", "CategoryName"=>"Specials"},
          {"CategoryID"=>"1632", "CategoryName"=>"Specialty Items"}]}},
     {"ProductCode"=>"GF-malbec",
      "Categories"=>
       {"Category"=>
         [{"CategoryID"=>"1514", "CategoryName"=>"Gourmet Food"},
          {"CategoryID"=>"1632", "CategoryName"=>"Specialty Items"}]}},
     {"ProductCode"=>"GF-olives",
      "Categories"=>
       {"Category"=>
         [{"CategoryID"=>"1514", "CategoryName"=>"Gourmet Food"},
          {"CategoryID"=>"1632", "CategoryName"=>"Specialty Items"}]}},
     {"ProductCode"=>"HC-flatiron",
      "Categories"=>
       {"Category"=>
         [{"CategoryID"=>"1513", "CategoryName"=>"Beauty"},
          {"CategoryID"=>"1515", "CategoryName"=>"Specials"},
          {"CategoryID"=>"1554", "CategoryName"=>"Hair Care"}]}}
    ]
  } 
}
```

then you can:

```
puts products['All_Products']['Product'].
     collect{ |product| product['Categories'] && product['Categories']['Category'] }.
     flatten.uniq
```

result:

```
[{"CategoryID"=>"1513", "CategoryName"=>"Beauty"},
 {"CategoryID"=>"1515", "CategoryName"=>"Specials"},
 {"CategoryID"=>"1553", "CategoryName"=>"Bath and Body"},
 {"CategoryID"=>"1514", "CategoryName"=>"Gourmet Food"}, 
 {"CategoryID"=>"1632", "CategoryName"=>"Specialty Items"}, 
 {"CategoryID"=>"1554", "CategoryName"=>"Hair Care"}]
```

Also, please try not to create variable names such as `p`, `puts`, `do` etc. They're reserved Ruby methods.